# how to expand array of pointer in composition c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have class company that has an object from insurance category and the object is array of pointers and the size of the array is 5. I want to expand it to 6 without changing the `Size`.

This is what I already have, but I get a run time error

```
*Insurance_category *temp = new Insurance_category[Size]; //Size is the old Size (5)
copy(*IC,*IC+Size,temp); //temp=IC
delete[] IC;
*IC=new Insurance_category[Size+add]; //IC is the object from the class insurance category
copy(temp,temp+Size+add,*IC); //IC=temp
Size+=add;                       

for(int y=Size-add;y<Size+add;y++)
{
    IC[y]->set_LevelName();
    IC[y]->set_OverallAnnualBenefit();
    IC[y]->set_PeriodOfCover();
}
```

Comment: One doesn't simply say `pleeeeeeaaaase` on StackOverflow.

Comment: What error is this? If `add > 0` then your for loop runs out of the array. The upper bound is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an array, try using a vector. A vector is resizable, that way you don't have to change the variable you call size.